# How to add zoomin, zoomout and pan functionality in line graph by using chartjs

Tags: php, html, charts

I am drawing line chart using chartjs and now I want to add zoomin and zoomout functionality to it. I searched for it and found relevant thing here:https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/blob/master/samples/zoom-log.html. But it is not exactly wanted I wanted. Here is what I am trying to make:http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/zooming-panning/. So my question is that how to achieve this in chart js.